# flutter getter called on null async memoizer

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

I am trying to use async memoizer to make a url call to a backend and return the value to my screen. Here is my code:

My Data Repository

```
 import 'package:new_app/data/trainer_repository.dart';
 import 'package:new_app/models/trainer.dart';
 import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'package:async/async.dart';

 class TrainerBLoc {
    final trainerSource = BehaviorSubject<Trainer>();
    final AsyncMemoizer _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();
    Stream<Trainer> get trainerStream => trainerSource.stream;

    Future<Trainer> fetchTrainer() async {
      return _memoizer.runOnce(() async {
      final trainer = await trainerRepository.getTrainer();
      return trainer;
    });
 }

 void dispose() {
 trainerSource?.close();
 }
}

final TrainerBLoc trainerBLoc = TrainerBLoc();
```

Trainer Model

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class Trainer extends Equatable {
   final String name;
   final String phoneNumber;
   final String email;
   final String image;
   final String state;
   final String lg;

  Trainer({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.phoneNumber,
    @required this.email,
    @required this.image,
    @required this.state,
    @required this.lg,
});


  @override
  List<Object> get props => [phoneNumber, name, email, image];
}
```

My Main Widget

```
class _TrainerScreenState extends State<TrainerScreen> {
  Future<Trainer> _trainer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _trainer = trainerBLoc.fetchTrainer();
    super.initState();
 }
 .....
```

But i get the error getter 'name' called on null. Without the memoizer, the code runs fine. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add **await** to the _memoizer.runOnce() since it is a async function.

```dart
Future<Trainer> fetchTrainer() async {
      return await _memoizer.runOnce(() async {
      final trainer = await trainerRepository.getTrainer();
      return trainer;
    });
```

trainerBLoc.fetchTrainer() is also a async function, you need to wait for the result before set it to the variable.

```dart
 @override
  void initState() {
    trainerBLoc.fetchTrainer().then((value){_trainer=value});
    super.initState();
 }
```

Comment: adding await to the _memoizer did it for me. Thanks